# How to get assembly output from building with Cargo?

Tags: assembly, rust, rust-cargo

While I've seen docs on using `rustc` directly to output assembly, having to manually extract commands used by Cargo and edit them to write assembly is tedious.

Is there a way to run Cargo that writes out assembly files?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can use Cargo's `cargo rustc` command to send arguments to `rustc` directly:

```
cargo rustc -- --emit asm
ls target/debug/deps/<crate_name>-<hash>.s
```

For optimized assembly:

```
cargo rustc --release -- --emit asm
ls target/release/deps/<crate_name>-<hash>.s
```

If you see multiple `<crate_name>-<hash>-<hash>.rcgu.s` files instead of a `<crate_name>-<hash>.s` file, disable incremental compilation by setting the environment variable `CARGO_INCREMENTAL=0`.

Comment: Is there a way to change the assembly type? Say I want ARM instead of x86

Comment: @davidanderle Supply an ARM target to `cargo rustc`, e.g. `cargo rustc --target aarch64-apple-ios --release -- --emit asm`. The assembly will be in `target/aarch64-apple-ios/release/deps/*.s`.

Comment: How to get intel asm?

Comment: You can get intel syntax with 
`cargo rustc -- --emit asm -C "llvm-args=-x86-asm-syntax=intel"`

Comment: for my particular project, adding `--emit asm` argument quadruples the compile time, and the result executable binary is 40% larger. Why does emitting assembly need so much time and why does the output binary file also change?

Answer (score 61):

Both existing answers (using `cargo rustc` and `RUSTFLAGS`) are the best ways to obtain assembly with standard tools. If you find yourself trying to look at assembly fairly often, you might want to consider using [**the `cargo asm` subcommand**](https://github.com/gnzlbg/cargo-asm). After installing it with `cargo install cargo-asm`, you can print assembly like:

```
cargo build --release
cargo asm my_crate::my_function
```

There are a few things to pay attention to, though:

- Unsure about the path of your function? Just run `cargo asm` and it will list all symbols you can inspect.
- You have to `cargo build --release` before trying to look at the assembly, because `cargo asm` (apparently) only looks at the already existing build-artifacts
- The code for the function you want to inspect has to be actually generated. For generic functions this means that the function has to be instantiated/monomorphized with a concrete type. If that doesn't happen in your crate, you can always add a dummy function at the top level that does everything you want to inspect the assembly of.

Comment: Output of cargo:  error: no such subcommand: `asm`

Comment: @Sebi2020 "After installing it with `cargo install cargo-asm`" <- did you do that?

Comment: Now use cargo-show-asm from https://crates.io/crates/cargo-show-asm

Answer (score 56):

In addition to kennytm's answer, you can also use the `RUSTFLAGS` environment variable and use the standard cargo commands:

```
RUSTFLAGS="--emit asm" cargo build
cat target/debug/deps/project_name-hash.s
```

Or in release mode (with optimizations):

```
RUSTFLAGS="--emit asm" cargo build --release
cat target/release/deps/project_name-hash.s
```

You can pass different values to the `--emit` parameter, *including* (but not limited to):

- `mir` (Rust intermediate representation)
- `llvm-ir` (LLVM intermediate representation)
- `llvm-bc` (LLVM byte code)
- `asm` (assembly)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Windows

Comment: A hacker which using windows. Interesting.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to look at the assembly output instead of saving it, e.g. to judge if it's well-optimized, then an easy option is to use:

https://rust.godbolt.org/

(don't forget to add `-O` to the Compiler options box)