# How do I find the assembly code for my function in a (release) Rust build?

Tags: assembly, rust, x86-64, compiler-explorer

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) seems to be able to reliably find the assembly code corresponding to a function. How can I do that myself, assuming a `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` toolchain, a regular (no attributes) function, and without extra tools like `cargo-asm`?

I know that to produce the assembly, I can use [rustc's `--emit asm` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219961/how-to-get-assembly-output-from-building-with-cargo). One might think that finding the function is easy as searching for its name in the .s file, but I found that it's not.

For instance, the .s file often doesn't even mention the function name, in which case adding `#[inline(never)]` to the function helps. Second, having found the label with the function name, how do you determine where the function ends? In my test crate, I found a second mention of the function name in a `.size` directive farther down – does that maybe mark the end of the function? Or is it maybe the first `retq` after the function start?

Assuming this goal is achievable, I hope to learn:

- What are the most reliable ways to find the start and end of a function?
- What are the prerequisites for getting suitable assembly files to do that?

Comment: Technically the `.size` can be anywhere but its form is usually `. - foo` where `.` is the current address hence it marks the end of the function. A function may have multiple return instructions so that's not a reliable way to identify it.

Comment: The [source code is available](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer), presumably containing the answer.

Comment: In C/C++, compilers have to produce a stand-alone definition for a function that's not `static`.  i.e. that could be called from another translation unit.  I don't really know Rust; if that's not the default then maybe you need to mark it as "global" or "exported" somehow.  That would still let it inline into some callers as well as making a stand-alone definition, but otherwise achieve the same goal as `inline(never)`

Answer (score 2):

Since there was no answer, I did a little bit of research and this should do the trick:

1. Make sure the function is used by `main()` in case of a binary crate, or by a `pub` function in case of a library crate (or is `pub` itself).
2. To avoid the compiler inlining your benchmark, mark it `#[inline(never)]`
3. Search for the function name, which should find the start, which looks like this:

```
    .type   <mangled_name>,@function
<mangled_name>:
    .cfi_startproc
```

4. Search for the end of the function, which is marked by:

```
.Lfunc_end<number>:
    .size   <mangled_name>, .Lfunc_end<number>-<mangled_name>
    .cfi_endproc
```

This can sometimes be preceded by a `retq`, but not reliably.

Those lines that start with a dot and do *not* end with a colon, like `.type`, are directives. The directives that the GNU assembler understands are documented [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/), and the output of `--emit asm` should be valid input to the GNU assembler.

### Compiler Explorer and `cargo-asm`

It seems that Compiler Explorer actually keeps the entire file and does not search for functions, it just filters out certain lines. At least that is what the [source code](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/blob/bc9d70dc513228641af2e4c61a9e2fa440b840cf/lib/asm-parser.js#L236-L438) seems to be doing.

`cargo-asm` specifically appears to look for [`.cfi_endproc` on Linux and Mac, and `.seh_endproc` on Windows](https://github.com/gnzlbg/cargo-asm/blob/577f890ebd4a09c8265710261e976fe7bfce8668/src/asm/parse.rs#L179-L187).

Comment: Right, Compiler Explorer just filters lines.  It works well when you compile a C++ source file that only has a few functions in it.