# Why is Docker producing different images when building my Rust program on macOS versus Ubuntu? Is this a bug in Docker?

Tags: macos, docker, ubuntu, rust, dockerfile

Here's my simple Rust program:

```
use std::time::SystemTime;

fn main() {
    let now = SystemTime::now();
    println!("{:?}", now);
}
```

And here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:1.50 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src
RUN cargo new --bin playground
WORKDIR /usr/src/playground
COPY Cargo.toml .
COPY Cargo.lock .
RUN cargo build --release
RUN rm -rf src
COPY src src
RUN cargo build --release

FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/playground/target/release/playground /usr/local/bin/playground
CMD [ "playground" ]
```

My builder image contains `cargo build --release` twice because the first time it builds my dependencies and the second time it builds my executable. I know the simple program above doesn't have external dependencies, but this is the setup I normally use and it greatly speeds up Docker builds when my `src` code has changed but my `Cargo.toml` hasn't changed (it builds in a few seconds versus a few minutes).

However, I get completely different results when I `docker build` and `docker run` this on macOS compared to Ubuntu.

On macOS, I get the system time, e.g.:

```
SystemTime { tv_sec: 1614652600, tv_nsec: 426791496 }
```

On Ubuntu, I get the default Rust program output:

```
Hello, world!
```

It appears that the executable generated by the first `cargo build --release` is cached when building on Ubuntu such that the second `cargo build --release` doesn't do anything (while it rebuilds the executable on macOS). **I'm not sure what is the "right" behavior, but as far as I know, Docker should not produce different images when building the same thing on two different operating systems? Is this a bug in Docker or do I fundamentally misunderstand how Docker works?**

Interestingly, this only happens when I `use` something. If I change my Rust program to:

```
fn main() {
    println!("CHANGED!");
}
```

Then I get `Hello, world!` on both macOS and Ubuntu. Note that I can get consistent behavior on both operating systems if I fix the issue by adding `RUN cargo clean` before the second `RUN cargo build --release`. However, I still think it's problematic that I get different images without this fix.

Note that I'm using macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7 with Docker Desktop Version 3.1.0, and I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 with Docker Version 19.03.6.

Comment: After some discussion with a colleague, I feel more confident that this is a bug with Docker Desktop for macOS, so I filed an issue here: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5408. If I'm mistaken, please let me know!

Comment: My answer would probably have been better for a comment but there wasn't enough room. I also didn't realize this question is already 2 years old. Hope you figured it out by now already.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a bug in Docker or do I fundamentally misunderstand how Docker works?

I think this is more of a Docker limitation than a bug.

> as far as I know, Docker should not produce different images when building the same thing on two different operating systems?

This is not entirely true. Docker does provide an "OS environment" to each container, but the kernel is always the host's kernel - Docker is not a full VM.

It is possible for a program to run differently on different OSes. Therefore it is possible to get different build results as well.

I am not convinced that's what is happening in this specific case, however. I think you might be right that there is some slight difference on the host or Docker side. I would suggest checking the modified and creation times on both the outside (host) side and inner (Docker) side of the containers of the `src` directory and `main.rs`