# How to compile x86 Assembly generated via rustc into an executable?

Tags: assembly, rust, gdb, ld, rust-cargo

I am having difficulties assembling the x86 Assembly that is compiled by the rustc compiler. I have tried various methods of assembling it, but am getting no output. The code in itself is very simple, it is just that the emitted Assembly does not execute properly, or at all.

I have tried 3 approaches:

1. compiling to assembly via rustc and further assembling that with rustc.
2. compiling to llvm bytecode, to llvm x86 assembly, and tried to compile that using clang and/or rustc (or even gcc, but that produces the same errors as clang)
3. using `as` and `ld`, wherein it can compile it to the Assembly, but not assemble any further.

In all the steps, I am able to generate the x86 Assembly just fine. The only issue that I am having is assembling that Assembly into an executable.

Crucial: The Assembly Compilation should include debug info. This is because I crucially need to pass it through GDB, for a thesis that I am working on.

---

Here are a sequence of events I tried:

Let's say I have a file: `main.rs`

```rust
pub fn main() {
    let mut j = 0;
    for i in 0..10 {
        j = j + 100;
        if i % 2 == 0 {
            j = j - 1;
        } else {
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Approach 1:**

```
$ rustc --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --emit=asm -o main.s main.rs
$ rustc main.s
```

Gives me a whole bunch of errors with the generated Assembly file:

```
error: unknown character escape: `b`
   --> your_code.s:381:11
    |
381 |     .asciz    "\b\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\b\000\000\000\000\000\000"
    |                 ^ unknown character escape
    |
    = help: for more information, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#literals>
help: if you meant to write a literal backslash (perhaps escaping in a regular expression), consider a raw string literal
    |
381 |     .asciz    r"\b\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\b\000\000\000\000\000\000"
    |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error: unknown character escape: `b`
   --> your_code.s:381:41
    |
381 |     .asciz    "\b\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\b\000\000\000\000\000\000"
    |                                               ^ unknown character escape
    |
    = help: for more information, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#literals>
help: if you meant to write a literal backslash (perhaps escaping in a regular expression), consider a raw string literal
    |
381 |     .asciz    r"\b\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\b\000\000\000\000\000\000"
    |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error: unknown character escape: `f`
   --> your_code.s:413:59
    |
413 |     .asciz    "\007\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\005\000\000\000\f\000\000"
    |                                                                 ^ unknown character escape
    |
    = help: for more information, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#literals>
help: if you meant to write a literal backslash (perhaps escaping in a regular expression), consider a raw string literal
    |
413 |     .asciz    r"\007\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\005\000\000\000\f\000\000"
    |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error: unknown character escape: `b`
   --> your_code.s:443:43
    |
443 |     .asciz    "\007\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\b\000\000\000\021\000\000"
    |                                                 ^ unknown character escape
    |
    = help: for more information, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#literals>
help: if you meant to write a literal backslash (perhaps escaping in a regular expression), consider a raw string literal
    |
443 |     .asciz    r"\007\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\b\000\000\000\021\000\000"
    |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error: expected item, found `.`
 --> your_code.s:1:2
  |
1 |     .text
  |     ^ expected item
  |
  = note: for a full list of items that can appear in modules, see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items.html>

error: aborting due to 5 previous errors
```

**Approach 2 (and 3, by extension, since they're giving the same errors)**

```
$ as -o main.o main.s
$ ld -o main main.o
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401000
ld: main.o: in function `std::rt::lang_start':
main.aaccb3f0a8cfdec6-cgu.0:(.text._ZN3std2rt10lang_start17h10f5244e46882c73E+0x23): undefined reference to `std::rt::lang_start_internal'
ld: main.o: in function `core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once':
main.aaccb3f0a8cfdec6-cgu.0:(.text._ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17h90749210ed415b5cE+0x1f): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
ld: main.o: in function `main::main':
main.aaccb3f0a8cfdec6-cgu.0:(.text._ZN4main4main17hd80a274883898d96E+0x99): undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
ld: main.aaccb3f0a8cfdec6-cgu.0:(.text._ZN4main4main17hd80a274883898d96E+0xca): undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
ld: main.aaccb3f0a8cfdec6-cgu.0:(.text._ZN4main4main17hd80a274883898d96E+0x11b): undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
ld: main.aaccb3f0a8cfdec6-cgu.0:(.text._ZN4main4main17hd80a274883898d96E+0x146): undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
ld: main.o:(.data.DW.ref.rust_eh_personality[DW.ref.rust_eh_personality]+0x0): undefined reference to `rust_eh_personality'
```

I would genuinely be grateful if anyone can guide me on how to achieve this final step, and debug assembly outputted by `rustc` in `GDB`.

Thank you for your time and help.

EDIT: Changed Compiling -> Assembling when necessary

Comment: `as` to assemble isn't showing any errors, so that's good.  Does `rustc` work to link the `.o`?  Bare `ld` doesn't link libraries or CRT startup code, so if you wanted to do that you'd have to check what options `rustc` passes to `ld` in addition to the `.o` files.  Same as with C, you don't link with `ld` you link with `gcc foo.o`, but you can use `gcc -v foo.o` to have it show you the commands it ran.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, ```rustc``` does not work for linking (which is what had me resort to bare ```ld```). It just gives me a error because none of the text is in ```UTF-8```. 

I was only able to find a similar discussion, where manual linking .o files via ```rustc``` did not work for them either: [link](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/manually-invoke-rustc-to-link-o-files-to-binary/87377).

I just need to figure this last step pretty much.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `cargo`?

Comment: Since Rust is LLVM based, I was able to link an object file with `clang ~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-05737cf45bd30456.so  <OBJFILE> -o test-rust`. When linking the object file generated from `rustc --emit=asm` and `as` starting from the code in your question, the binary executed fine and IDA seems to show code compatible with the source, however take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thank you for the comment!! This approach worked!! I might still try to compile larger programs, but for now this is a good bodge. I can even run it in GDB and do my tracing as needed. Might still need to test it in Cargo when compiling larger programs, so I think the question (or a follow up) may be needed.

Comment: @Jmb Thank you for the question. I'm mainly working on tracing Assembly execution from single programs. Will Cargo have some inherent benefits?? I do plan on to try the tracing for full large programs.

Comment: Well, `cargo` handles all the compilation details, not just dependencies. In particular, `cargo` knows how to call the linker and what options to pass to it so you don't need to concern yourself with those details.

Comment: @Jmb The main thing that I need to do is to actually get the x86 Asm emitted out first, and then assemble that with debugging symbols to pass it in ```GDB```. Is there a way that ```cargo``` can handle this? So far I have mainly been playing with just the barebones ```rustc``` compiler (my research is in analyzing the Asm files from C++ and Rust under certain conditions, so if ```cargo``` can do the linking for the Asm in a way that I can debug that Asm (not the original RUST code), that'd be super helpful!! :D

Comment: AFAIK `cargo` can't start from an ASM file. But you don't need the ASM file to debug in assembly mode, `gdb` can do that even for a file compiled from C or Rust source. Also if you need to analyze the ASM independently, [`cargo` can emit that too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39220789/5397009).

Comment: And even if in the end you prefer typing the individual commands by hand, if you give `cargo` the `-v` option, it will show you the commands it uses, so you can use them as a starting point.